# How can I convert new Chart to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, type-conversion, chartjs-2.6.0

Could I convert a new Chart to HTML object?

It's my code.

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: dates,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Caudal Minimo',
                data: CMN,
                borderColor: "rgb(102, 153, 255)",
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
                fill: false,
            }]
        }
    };

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);


new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
  .setHTML(document.getElementById("canvas"))
  .addTo(map);
```

My HTML

```
<div class="work-top">
    <div id='map' style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 1000px;">
    </div>
    <canvas id='canvas' style="min-width: 315px; height: 400px; margin: -4px"></canvas>
</div>
```

this is the result in my popup -> **[object HTMLCanvasElement]**

Comment: There's no "chart" element in HTML, hence you can't convert a chart object to a HTML element.

Comment: I've found the answer. I had to change Set method

    new mapboxgl.Popup()
      .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
      .setDOMContent(document.getElementById("canvas"))
      .addTo(map);